# Postfix suggests a bunch of other packages on install.What are they and should I install them?

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, mta

Postfix suggests these packages on install:

```
procmail
postfix-mysql
postfix-pgsql
postfix-ldap
postfix-pcre
sasl2-bin
dovecot-common
postfix-cdb
postfix-doc
```

I know what procmail and dovecot are. It's the rest I'd like to know about.

Info about my server: it's a VPS and I am the only user. I have multiple domains. I plan to use user accounts for email addresses because that sounded simplest. So these would be my email addresses: me@domain1.com, me@domain2.com, etc.

I set up an MX record pointing at my server's IP address which is mail.mydomain.com. (There is no corresponding mail subdomain, that's just the address of the MX record.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you have a suggestion on whether to use dovecot or procmail, that would be appreciated also.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/ has them all with a short description. sas12-bin does not exist for ubuntu(?) we do have a libsasl so your instructions might be for another OS (suse/redhat)?

Comment: Nope, it's ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: It is not SAS12-BIN it is SASL2-BIN: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/sasl2-bin

Comment: Ah ha. That l looked like a 1. Will update.

Comment: >> Place for a funny, off-topic comment on typing the package names instead of copy-pasting. <<

Answer (score 0):

**sasl2-bin**

> This is the Cyrus SASL API implementation, version 2.1. See package  libsasl2-2 and RFC 2222 for more information.
>
> This package contains administration programs for the SASL users database and common binary files for plugin modules.

**[postfix-mysq](http://www.postfix.org/MYSQL_README.html)l, [postfix-pgsq](http://www.postfix.org/PGSQL_README.html)l, [postfix-ldap](http://www.postfix.org/LDAP_README.html), [postfix-pcre](http://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html), [postfix-cdb](http://www.postfix.org/CDB_README.html)**

Are all connections to external programmas: MySQK, Postgres, Lightweight Directory Access Protocol, Perl Compatible Regular Expressions support, Constant DataBase

**postfix-doc**

[Documentation](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/postfix-doc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to get more information about a package:

```
apt-cache show <package_name>
```

Here are my results running on 14.04 server:

```
list="procmail postfix-mysql postfix-pgsql postfix-ldap postfix-pcre sasl2-bin dovecot-common postfix-cdb postfix-doc"; for p in $list; do apt-cache show $p | grep Description-en | sed -e "s/Description\-en/$p/"; done

procmail: Versatile e-mail processor
postfix-mysql: MySQL map support for Postfix
postfix-pgsql: PostgreSQL map support for Postfix
postfix-ldap: LDAP map support for Postfix
postfix-pcre: PCRE map support for Postfix
sasl2-bin: Cyrus SASL - administration programs for SASL users database
postfix-cdb: CDB map support for Postfix
postfix-doc: Documentation for Postfix
```